# mandb generates all possible languages in /var/cache/man

Tags: cron, man, cache-directory

In Debian 12, the following command is run weekly:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /dev/null --startas /usr/bin/mandb --oknodo --chuid man -- --quiet
```

which generates man caches in `/var/cache/man`

But looking in that directory, I see all possible languages are being generated:

```
...
./zh_CN
./zh_CN/cat1
./zh_CN/cat5
./zh_CN/cat8
./zh_CN/index.db
./zh_TW
./zh_TW/cat1
./zh_TW/cat5
./zh_TW/cat8
./zh_TW/index.db
```

I have language set to English, How do I prevent nonsense languages being generated?

Comment: Don't call them `nonsense`. Try editing `/etc/manpath.config` which should have a list of cache directories to act upon and comment out all the ones you do not wish to be regenerated and see how far you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mandb` doesn’t generate all possible languages, it generates database caches for all installed manpages. Compare the contents of `/usr/share/man` and `/var/cache/man`: you’ll see that the languages in the latter correspond to the languages in the former.

If you don’t need certain languages, you can remove the corresponding manpages entirely. Create a configuration file for `dpkg`, *e.g.* `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/locales`, containing

```
path-exclude=/usr/share/man/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/man[1-9]/*
path-include=/usr/share/man/en*/*
```

(for English only; add further `path-include` entries if you want other languages). This will prevent `dpkg` from installing other manpages in future. Once that’s done, remove the existing directories you don’t need, *e.g.*

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/man/zh* /var/cache/man/zh*
```